# How to show the selected item name in the drop down list?

Tags: php, javascript, html, html-select

I have created a 'Insert_Product' page in which I have some product related fields and a drop down box which is showing 'Category' and 'Sub_category' from which the specific product relates.

When I update any specific product it opens the Product page and Fetches the data from database in the form Fields, but in the drop down list it shows the first given name. I want it to select the selected category from which the Product belongs.

Right now its showing the first item from the database.

```
        $select_query=  "select * from products LEFT JOIN product_description 
        ON products.product_id='".$id."' and 
        product_description.product_id='".$id."' 
        where products.product_id='".$id."'     ";

        $sub_category_id2 = $fetch_select['sub_category_id'];




        echo "<tr><td>Select Category </td><td><select name='category'>";

        $select_query=          'Select * from category';

        $select_query_run =     mysql_query($select_query);

        $sub_category_query=   "Select * from sub_categories 
                     where category_id='".$select_query_array['category_id']."'";


        while ($select_query_array=   mysql_fetch_array($select_query_run) ) 
        {
         echo

         "<optgroup label='".$select_query_array['name']."' >".
        $sub_category_query="Select * from sub_categories 
        where category_id='".$select_query_array['category_id']."'";


        $sub_query_run=         mysql_query($sub_category_query);

        while   ($sub_query_run_fetch=   mysql_fetch_array($sub_query_run) ) 
         {

            echo    'sub1 '.$sub_category_id =  
                        $sub_query_run_fetch['sub_category_id'] ;

                echo 
                "<option value=\"$sub_category_id\"";

                    if($sub_category_id==$sub_category_id2)

                echo ' selected="selected"';

                echo " >" .
                htmlspecialchars($sub_query_run_fetch['sub_category_name']) . "</option>";
                 }

                    echo "</optgroup>";
             }
```

[image]

```
                <tr><td>Select Category </td><td>


<select name='category'><optgroup label='Rings' >Select * from sub_categories 
                            where category_id='1'sub1 1<option value="1" >Gold</option>sub1 2<option value="2" >Silver</option>sub1 3<option value="3" >Diamond</option></optgroup><optgroup label='Bracelets' >Select * from sub_categories 
                            where category_id='2'sub1 4<option value="4" >Diamond</option>sub1 6<option value="6" >Gold</option>sub1 7<option value="7" >Silver</option></optgroup><optgroup label='Necklaces' >Select * from sub_categories 
                            where category_id='3'sub1 10<option value="10" >Diamond</option>sub1 11<option value="11" >Gold</option>sub1 12<option value="12" >Silver</option></optgroup><optgroup label='Earrings' >Select * from sub_categories 
                            where category_id='4'sub1 16<option value="16" >Diamonds</option>sub1 17<option value="17" >Gold</option>sub1 18<option value="18" >Silver</option></optgroup><optgroup label='Chains' >Select * from sub_categories 
                            where category_id='5'sub1 27<option value="27" >Diamond</option>sub1 28<option value="28" >Gold</option>sub1 29<option value="29" >Silver</option></optgroup><optgroup label='Pendants' >Select * from sub_categories 
                            where category_id='6'sub1 19<option value="19" >Diamond</option>sub1 20<option value="20" >Gold</option>sub1 21<option value="21" >Silver</option></optgroup><optgroup label='Brooches' >Select * from sub_categories 
                            where category_id='7'sub1 5<option value="5" >Silver</option>sub1 22<option value="22" >Gold</option>sub1 23<option value="23" >Diamond</option></optgroup><optgroup label='Charms' >Select * from sub_categories 
                            where category_id='8'sub1 24<option value="24" >Diamond</option>sub1 25<option value="25" >Gold</option>sub1 26<option value="26" >Silver</option></optgroup></br></div></div></br>

</select>
```

Comment: Left video making :P ??

Comment: Never :P -Video making only on Sundays :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a space before `selected`

```
echo " selected";
```

without it, 'selected' is becoming part of the value. you should also quote your value for html correctness.

```
echo "<option value=\"$sub_category_id\"";
```

Update:

Looks like you're missing a query? $sub_category_id2 is being set to an undefined variable:

```
    $select_query=  "select * from products LEFT JOIN product_description 
    ON products.product_id='".$id."' and 
    product_description.product_id='".$id."' 
    where products.product_id='".$id."'     ";

    // MISSING QUERY HERE - $fetch_select is not defined

    $sub_category_id2 = $fetch_select['sub_category_id'];
```

Comment: I have updated my code and add image of my Page. Kindly check it.

Comment: your code `echo "selected= 'selected'";` is wrong. it should be `echo " selected";` OR `echo ' selected="selected"';` The space goes at the beginning of the string.

Comment: I have change it to echo " selected"; but still its not working correctly.

Comment: can you add the actual HTML code that is generated for that select box?

Comment: that's not the generated code. use view source on the web page. need to see the code between `<select></select>` that contains the options that aren't selecting properly

Comment: As you can see in your HTML code, it never prints `selected="selected"` so $sub_category_id is never equal to $sub_category_id2. You should verify `$sub_category_id2` is the value you expect (it looks like you meant to execute $select_query, but didn't). Based on the extraneous echo's, `$sub_category_id` is fine. You'll want to start removing the extra echo's that print the queries and "sub1 X".

Comment: Thank you so much for pointing this out. I just changed `$sub_category_id2` to `global $sub_category_id2;` and its working fine.